# Перевести в верхний регистр фамилии с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++, форматирование

Руководство ждёт от меня много бейджиков для конференции. На бейджике, по желанию руководства, фамилия должна быть в верхнем регистре (а имя в нижнем). То есть, я получил массив данных вида:

1. Ivan Ivanov
2. Petr Petrov

Я должен дать быстро руководству на выход:

1. Ivan IVANOV
2. Petr PETROV

У меня есть редактор `notepad`, он кажется понимает регулярные выражения.

**Вопрос:** Подскажите мне регулярное выражение, которое переведёт фамилию в верхний регистр? Все фамилии русские - заканчиваются на in(a), ov(a).

**PS.** Если есть какая-то простенькая программа для работы с такими задачами - тоже подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Замените `\h.+` (или `\S+$`) на `\U$0`

Comment: А что, мой вариант не работает?

Answer (score 5):

Notepad++

Искать: `(\w+)\s+(\w+)`

Заменить: `$1 \U$2`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, ваше выражение работает шикарно. К моему удивлению, оно правильно заменило  даже типично еврейские фамилии. Во-вторых, оно работает, и я не понимаю как. Я с удовольствием приму ваш ответ, но распишите пожалуйста, (очень надо!) по-символьно, что делается в первой строке и во второй.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, тут необходимо привести к верхнему регистру целое последнее на строке слово.

Используйте

**Найти**:                `\S+$` (или `\w+$`)
**Заменить на**:         `\U$0`

**Подробности**

- `\w+` - 1 и более букво-цифровых символов, а также символов `_`
- `\S+` - 1 и более символов, отличных от пробельных
- `$` - конец строки.

В шаблоне замены оператор `\U` приводит все последующие символы к верхнему регистру (до оператора `\E`, но так как его нет, то до конца совпадения), а `$0` подставляет целое совпадение.

Если использовать оператор `\L` вместо `\U`, строки будут приведены к нижнему регистру.

***Настройки и демо***:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]